# When using jdbctemplate with spring, should I have a base class?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm moving from hibernate to jdbctemplate in spring, and need some guidance.

I'm going to create a `UserDao` and then a `UserDaoImpl`.

In my servlet.xml file I have my datasource bean created.

Now I'm reading this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

It says to have a private method:

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

So can I create my UserDaoImpl like this:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

}
```

1. Do I need the set datasource there?  Or can I use some kind of annotation?
2. Could I move this code to a base class like GenericDao/ GenericDaoImpl?
   (if so, do I keep the jdbcTempalte as private or protected?

With hibernate I was able to add basic queries in my base class using generics, I'm guessing I can't do that with jdbc since nothing is really mapped to my entities correct?

**update**

So my GenericDaoImpl looks like:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> extends JdbcDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T> {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

 }
```

Then my UserDaoImpl looks like:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao {

}
```

1. I can't use this.jdbcTemplate in my methods now?  What do I do?
2. In my GenericDaoImpl I can have a setDataSource as it is marked final by JdbcDaoSupport.
   How do I **autowire** the datasource now?

Comment: The datasource can be moved to a base class and set via an annotation or XML config. Are you really using Spring 2.0?

Comment: No I'm using spring 3.0.6 why?

Comment: Because you linked to 2.0 docs.

Comment: your right, thanks for that now I see the annotations I can use (Repository and autowired).

Comment: What does this mean: "If you are using Spring's JdbcDaoSupport class, and your various JDBC-backed DAO classes extend from it, then your sub-class inherits a setDataSource(..) method from the JdbcDaoSupport class. You can choose whether to inherit from this class. The JdbcDaoSupport class is provided as a convenience only."

Comment: @Dave please see my updates above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using Spring 3, the data source can be injected into a parent DAO class using either XML configuration or annotations. In XML the "child" beans can use the `extends` keyword to use the superclass's `dataSource`.

The [`JdbcDaoSupport` class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html) is a small utility class that bundles up some common functionality, like the `dataSource` and `jdbcTemplate` properties (and some other things). It's just one of those little convenience classes that people create for themselves anyway, so it's provided instead.

Use `getDataSource()` to retrieve the data source. You don't *need* a `setDataSource()`, there's aleady one in `JdbcDaoSupport`; what would you do differently? If you *really* need one, then you likely don't want to use `JdbcDaoSupport`. It's relatively unusual to need anything beyond a simple getter/setter.

Comment: but how do I autowire the datasource in my GenericDaoImpl?  I'm getting an error saying: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.abc.dao.GenericDaoImpl.dataSource;

Comment: @Blankman Why does your JdbcDaoSupport have its own dataSource member?

Comment: @Dave I thought I had to define it so I could add the annotation to autowire it.

Comment: removing it I get: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) for the UserDaoImpl file.

Comment: Oh, with annotations. IIRC there was a JIRA filed about this like a million years ago ([or 3.5](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4339)), apparently nothing ever came of this (re: the `final` part). I think you're probably out of luck unless you create your own abstract subclass, or just skip it. Kind of a pain. Or you could do that part in XML, perhaps; not sure.

Comment: ok so I removed the @Repository and manually added the bean to my xml and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @Blankman Ah, cool. Yeah, I suspect some of those utility classes haven't really been updated to the "new world" of annotations (obviously :( I don't notice it as much because I still do a fair amount of that infrastructural work in XML.